# Facebook endpoint to get user's feeds/posts

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

So I want to get a user's feeds (or lets say user's posts); based on [this documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/feed#readperms) I'm calling the following endpoint:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{USER_ID}/feed?access_token={MY_ACCESS_TOKEN}
https://graph.facebook.com/{USER_ID}/posts?access_token={MY_ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

But this is giving me an empty data array; although there are public posts by the user! Am I doing something wrong? Should the user give the permission to my app?

Although the following end point works (which shows user general info), but that's not what I want; I want just a user's posts

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{USER_ID}?access_token={MY_ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

Thanks

Comment: What permissions does the access token have? What does the documentation say you need?

Comment: Documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/feed#readperms) says "Your app needs user_posts permission from the person who created the post or the person tagged in the post.", but how can I get the user_posts permission from the my user account?

Comment: Your app ask you for that permission and you accept

Comment: Thanks @WizKid, But still I dont know how I can ask for permission, could you please be more specific? I couldn't figure out which endpoint to call to get the permission?

Comment: You use Facebook Login: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.2

Answer (score 0):

You have to use facebook login and request permissions from the user to access their posts : "user_posts". This [document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3) covers how to request permissions with faceboook login. Once you are granted the user_posts permission, you can use the [access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens) you obtained from the user in your call to get the users feed.